# Is it good to use minterpolate in FFmpeg for reducing blurred frames

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, mpdecimate

I'm using FFMPEG to slice png files from videos.

I'm slicing the videos in fps between 1-3 depending on some video metadata.
I can see that when the subjects in the video moving fast or the camera are not steady I will get blurred frames. I try to research how I can solve it (The quality of these frames is my main goal) and I tackled the minterpolate option.

I think that if I will use the blend option that will mean the 3 frames to 1 the "noise" of the blurred subjects will reduce.

So my current command now is like this:

```
./ffmpeg -i "/home/dev/ffmpeg/test/input/@3.mp4" -vf minterpolate=fps=1:mi_mode=blend,mpdecimate=hi=11456:lo=6720:frac=0.5 -vsync 0  "/home/dev/ffmpeg/test/output/3/(#%04d).png"
```

Am I right? Do you think of a better way to use FFMPEG to solve my problem?

Comment: If your destination fps would be a divisor of original fps (ex. for original fps=30 you could select destination fps 1, 3, 5, etc; for original=10 you could select 1, 2, 5) you will need no interpolation, just original video frames can be used. Also you can achieve that with fractional fps (ex. 3 frames per 2 seconds) if you just select every n'th original frame from video without interpolation.

Comment: @Oliort. Thanks. Can you share an example for selecting 1 frame per 2 seconds using FFMPEG?

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1274661/selecting-one-every-n-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can create a better interpolation result if you use the `mci` method in ffmpeg, rather than the `blend` method. There are also more advanced techniques available.

If I understand you correctly you have a blurred image (let's call it B, in the middle) between two non-blurred images (let's call them A on the left and C on the right). Now you want to replace the middle frame B by a non-blurred version of B.

[image: A] [image: B blurred] [image: C]

The `minterpolate` [filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate) is used for interpolating in ffmpeg. It has two different approaches. A `blend` mode, which fades out A and then fades in C to generate a new image for B.

### Blend

If I run it with `ffmpeg  -i %02d.png -framerate 10 -vf minterpolate=fps=20:mi_mode=blend test-%02d.png` I get the following image.

[image: A] [image: B blend] [image: C]

### Motion estimation

You can also use the motion estimation or `mci` mode, which allows you to do motion based interpolation. You can call it by changing the mode: `ffmpeg  -i %02d.png -framerate 10 -vf minterpolate=fps=20:mi_mode=mci test-%02d.png` That generates a circle in the middle.

[image: A] [image: B mci] [image: C]

### Going further

The ffmpeg mci mode uses a [classic](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/334974?casa_token=IToVR6c39N4AAAAA:oUbn0HdbcJTK5FveKluDMzgNyy0bNuvjkGxbTBiw04-xiGKRjgHeOpdkzlTBMQ6lDcCvu63gMg) algorithm. There are some more advanced [optical flow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html) and [neural network](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/html/Jiang_Super_SloMo_High_CVPR_2018_paper.html) based approaches available. Which can give better [results](https://youtu.be/MjViy6kyiqs) with more complex images and with more complex motion fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the most informative and important answer I received in StackOverflow:) Appreciate it.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts for explaining different methods so smoothly.... Thanks man this really worked for me 