# Average between images results in a darker image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, average, video-processing

I'm trying to create the slow-motion of a 5 second video. In order to maintain the same frame-rate I need more frames. I extracted all the frames from the video and doubled them in number by creating new ones. Every frame has been combined with its successor to create an average frame to insert between them.

```
average = (predecessor + successor)/2
```

The result is *spatially* correct but it isn't in terms of colour. The average image is significantly darker than the originals. I'm trying to slow down a video of Federer playing tennis. The average image finds a middle ground between the original image and its successor. This effect can be seen between frames where the players and ball move significantly. The images below show the difference in colour that I'm trying to eliminate (*Left*: average, *Right*: Original)

[image][image: Predecessor (Original)]

Why does this happen? Is there any better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?.

Comment: In MATLAB, adding up two uint8 arrays uses saturated addition: 200 + 200 = 255. Convert both to floating-point to compute the mean, then convert back to uint8.

Comment: exactly. what does `average = uint8((single(predecessor) + single(successor))/2)` return?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you, this solved my problem. If you want you can post this as an answer so that I can give it the green check

Comment: For the actual task at hand I would suggest using something like `ffmpeg` to generate interpolated frames instead. It can do simple blending like this, but also has tricks for doing motion compensation. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152626/is-it-good-to-use-minterpolate-in-ffmpeg-for-reducing-blurred-frames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with integer arrays, MATLAB uses [saturation arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic). This means that `uint8(200) + uint8(200) == uint8(255)`.

Assuming your images are uint8, adding up two white pixels leads to saturation, maximally bright white, which you then divide by two to get medium gray.

To avoid this convert the images to a floating-point type, MATLAB defaults to `double`:

```
average = uint8((double(predecessor) + double(successor))/2);
```

But you can also use `single` if you’re worried about memory usage, [as suggested by Ander in a comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606375/average-between-images-results-in-a-darker-image/76606671#comment135066254_76606375).

Comment: My memory optimizing hat is always on because I am used to work with 2000^3 images, but indeed, `double` is good enough!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I also usually work with single-precision floats, it's enough precision for most applications in image processing. It's just that in MATLAB it's easier to work with `double` most of the time.